# Is it possible to use Linqpad with a Repository and UnitOfWork pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, linqpad

In my controllers, I initialize my unit of work and repository patterns as follows:

```
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IRepository<Website> _repository;

    public ProjectsController() { }

    public ProjectsController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWorkAsync,
        IRepository<Website> repository)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWorkAsync;
        _repository = repository;
    }
```

And my basic usage is as follows:

```
                    var website = _repository
                        .Query()
                        .Select()
                        .Single(u => u.UserId == userId && u.WebsiteGuid == websiteGuid);
```

I would like to use Linqpad to test out the queries, and would like to know if and how to use Linqpad to do this.

I first make a connection to the db context, then connect to the Repository.dll to avoid the following errors:

> The type 'Repository.Pattern.DataContext.IDataContextAsync' is defined
>   in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'Repository.Pattern, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. (Press F4)
>
> The type 'Repository.Pattern.DataContext.IDataContext' is defined in
>   an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'Repository.Pattern, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

So now that everything is connected, I'm at a loss on how to proceed.

Comment: You might be able to use LinqPad for this, but this also seems like something I would have in an actual Intregration and/or Unit Testing project in (or associated with) my solution. I even like to use test projects for what amount to sanity checks that I'm not even committing to source control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Sorax's tip, instead of using C# statement(s), I changed the language to C# program.

I added a reference to Repository.Pattern.Ef6\bin\Repository.Pattern.Ef6.dll and wrote a basic working query as follows:

```
void Main()
{
     //IRepository<Website> _repository =  ;

    var _repository = new Repository.Pattern.Ef6.Repository<Website>(this);

    var website = _repository
        .Query()
        .Select();

    website.Dump("The Oputput...");
}
```

Comment: You neglected to mention that you must Add New Connection of type DB Context, and fill out all those fields, for this to work properly. And as far as UnitOfWOrk goes, this is what mine looked like:  ```var uow = new UnitOfWork(this);
 var repo = new Repository<Product>(this,uow);```

Answer (score 2):

I'm making some assumptions here, such as your repository has a dependency on the DBContext connection you created. So it should just be a matter of initializing an instance:

```
var userId = new Guid("...");
var websiteGuid = new Guid("...");
var _repository = new Repository<Website>(this);

var website = _repository
.Query()
.Select()
.Single(u => u.UserId == userId && u.WebsiteGuid == websiteGuid);

website
.Dump();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error when I try to initialize the repo:  `) or end of expression expected (change the Query Language to 'C# Statements' for multi-statement queries)`

Comment: Press Ctrl+2 to change the selected Language to "C# Statement(s)"